# Web Requests C#,Java

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, httpwebrequest

I am trying to shorten the time it takes HttpWebRequest or WebClient to get a string from url,using C#, it takes about 2000ms to get the string.

Using Java I can get the string in about 300ms. (I am new to java, please see code below)

In c# I have tried setting `request.Proxy = null` and `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false` with no clear difference.

I don't know if C# and Java codes below are comparable, However I would like to get the data in a shorter time if possible using C#.

Java:

```
try {

                URL url = new URL("SomeURL");
                InputStream is = url.openStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                    br.close();
                    is.close();


} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

C#:

```
using (WebClient nn = new WebClient()) {
                nn.Proxy = null;

                string SContent = await nn.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
                return SContent;
}
```

or:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
       request.Method = "GET";
        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync()) {

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string SContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return SContent;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does `DownloadString`take the same amount of time?

Comment: can you post HttpWebRequest  code also

Comment: @ CodingYoshi, yes DownloadString takes about the same time but blocks while downloading

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga Please see edited question

Comment: @YarH What version of `Xamarin.Android` are you using? What HttpClient handler implementation are you using? `URL.openStream` is fairly low-level and as long as you know exactly what you are getting in the response (character-set, max. length, etc...) (i.e. you control the server response) and are handling ioexceptions/timeouts, etc... it will beat using a Java `URLConnection`, smoke `HttpClient` and blow away `WebClient`.

Comment: @YarH IMHO: When writing "native" Xamarin.Android code, I use HttpClient only when I need C# code compatibility with 3rd-party libs as the performance (memory consumed and CPU) is poor compared to `URLConnection` (I tend to use `URLConnection.openStream` vs. `URL.openStream` more due to its feature set). Plus when using the AndroidClientHandler version of HttpClient everything is going across the Java<->C# bridge anyway so you might as well use the Java http(s) implementations.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you, using HttpClient and changing httpclient handler to AndroidClientHandler " var client = new HttpClient(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler ()); " reduced the time to about 1100, which is good. I think this is the the closest it will get to URL.openStream in terms of speed. I would like to mark your comment as the answer if you could resubmit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code below will be faster than Java's URL.openStream or URLConnection, but it sure is succint. I wouldn't use `HttpWebRequest` anymore. Microsoft recommends using `HttpClient`.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharp.Console
{
    public class Program
    {
        // Make HttpClient a static member so it's available for the lifetime of the application.
        private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string body = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com");
            System.Console.WriteLine(body);
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note:** to be able to use async on your `Main` method in a Console Application, you need to use C# language specification 7.1 or up. (Project properties, Debug, Advanced, Language version).